# Are Snowball & SnowballC packages different in R?

Tags: r, stemming, tm, snowball

I am using `stemDocument` for stemming text document using `tm` package in R. Example code:

```
data("crude")
crude[[1]]
stemDocument(crude[[1]])
```

I get an error message:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘Snowball’

I have installed `SnowballC` package and unable to find Snowball package. Below is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8/C/en_CA.UTF-8/en_CA.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] SnowballC_0.5 tm_0.5-8.3   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] slam_0.1-31  tools_2.15.3
```

Does it require any other package or Snowball?

Comment: You should look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23379961/alternatives-to-snowball-for-stemming-text-in-r?rq=1).  The comments suggest that an update to `tm` may be needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an older version of `pkg:tm`. The current version of `tm` has a DESCRIPTION file that lists `SnowballC` as a "Suggests". Older versions suggested Snowball.

```
Package: tm
Title: Text Mining Package
Version: 0.5-10
Date: 2014-01-07
Authors@R: c(person("Ingo", "Feinerer", role = c("aut", "cre"),
                    email = "feinerer@logic.at"),
             person("Kurt", "Hornik", role = "aut"),
             person("Artifex Software, Inc.", role = c("ctb", "cph"),
                    comment = "pdf_info.ps taken from GPL Ghostscript"))
Depends: R (>= 2.14.0)
Imports: parallel, slam (>= 0.1-31)
Suggests: filehash, proxy, Rcampdf, Rgraphviz, Rpoppler, SnowballC, XML
```

This is the message you currently get from CRAN:

```
Package ‘Snowball’ was removed from the CRAN repository.

Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.

Archived on 2014-03-16 at the request of the maintainer.
```

You should update to the current version of `tm`.  Try this:

```
update.packages("tm",  checkBuilt = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.That was really helpful. Updating tm package didn`t work. But updating R from 2.15.3 to 3.1 and then installing tm package & SnowballC did work.

Answer (score 13):

Just try to install the `SnowballC` packages to R

```
install.packages("SnowballC")

library(SnowballC)
```

It should work.